# Incompatible sender/receiver arguments

Tags: c++, qt

**Hello veryone**  Please, help me to solve this probleme...

File.h

```
public slots:
void Manage_User_Connexion(QString UserName, QString Password);
```

file.cpp

```
   QObject::connect(PbLogin,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(Manage_User_Connexion(QString,QString)));
```

And I get this error: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments

Thank for your helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signal `clicked()` probably does not have any arguments. So you cannot connect it to a slot which expects two `QString` arguments. The arguments passed to signal when it is emitted are supposed to be passed to the slot. If the arguments are not compatible, then this cannot be done. You need to redesign your code, you probably should read more about the purpose of signals and slots mechanism because you probably do not fully understand how they work and what they are used for.

Without seeing more of your code we cannot help you find any solution.

PS: Do not use old Qt4 style of connections. Use new Qt5 style of connections, see https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax